# How to save settings a TabControl with new TabPages? Visual Studio and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tabcontrol

Add new pages:

```
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage mytab = new TabPage();
    mytab.Text = "New Tabpage";
    tabControl2.TabPages.Add(mytab);
}
```

How to save settings for new tabpages in Form. I want to keep the new added tabs but I can not make them stay

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to know is the number of `TabPages` and, perhaps, the `Text` for each one.  In that case, all you need is either a single `int` or else a `StringCollection` in settings.  If you use a `StringCollection`, you'd loop through it and create a `TabPage` for each item when loading and loop through the `TabPages` and add an item when saving.